# Append Child - Document Error 8

Tags: javascript, flash, dom, object, append

So I'm trying to create an object so I can replace the value of a param (which apparently isn't possible via JS) so I'm creating it and I keep getting a Document Error 8.

```
var container = document.getElementById('player');
var obj = document.createElement('object');

obj.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-shockwave-flash');
var p1 = obj.appendChild('param');
var p2 = obj.appendChild('param');
var p3 = obj.appendChild('param');
var p4 = obj.appendChild('param');

p1.setAttribute('name', 'allowFullScreen');
p1.setAttribute('value', 'true');

p2.setAttribute('name', 'allowScriptAccess');
p2.setAttribute('value', 'always');

p3.setAttribute('name', 'allowNetworking');
p3.setAttribute('value', 'all');

p4.setAttribute('name', 'flashvars');
p4.setAttribute('value', 'test');
```

I thought it was because I didn't add the object to html but I tried that via appendChild and still had the same problem...

Comment: Try [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), its more fun than reinventing the wheel ...

Comment: The [DOM 2 appendChild](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-184E7107) method requires a DOM Node as an argument, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.createElement`:

```
var p1 = obj.appendChild( document.createElement('param') );
```